# chain conditional sentences

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure, questions

> If he’s not here by 2:30, I’ll call his parents.
> If you sent a message, I’ll reply.
> If Jane’s fever hasn’t gone down, Anna will take her to the hospital.
> If the client is here, I’ll be sure to accompany him.

These are my answers for an assignment, the assignment told us to write down 4 conditional chain sentences. I wrote these 4 as answers but my teacher gave me an awful score and won't tell me the reason. Would someone kindly explained the reason? English is not my first language, so would appreciate if you could explained it to me because no one around me knew the reasons as well. Much thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The only way to know is to ask your teacher.  Your sentences are grammatically correct, so the reason for a bad score must be that you aren't doing what the teacher asked you to do. For example, perhaps she told you to only use second conditionals.  Or perhaps this was just the first question out of ten.

But I can guess what "conditional chains" means. This isn't a standard term in grammar, but I used to play a *game* of conditional chains. The point was the result of the first sentence should be the condition of the second

> If he’s not here by 2:30, I’ll call his parents.
> If I call his parent's they will get worried.
> If they get worried, they might go to search for him at the old church.
> If they go to the old church at night, then they will be attacked by zombies.
> If they get attacked by zombies ....

... Okay,  well that was a weird example, but you get the idea of the game. You try to make a funny story from "If ...., then...." sentences, each one linking to the next one like in a chain.

I guess this is what your teacher wanted.